# With exim4 and notmuch, should .Archive be a file or a folder?

Tags: imap, exim, courier

I'm following [The Hacker's Replacement for Gmail](http://dbpmail.net/essays/2013-06-29-hackers-replacement-for-gmail.html), using (as suggested) Debian 7 on a VPS.

If I configure it for "normal" IMAP I can successfully receive email into INBOX. So I'm doing something right. However the idea here is instead to put the mail in an Archive folder, then use notmuch to tag and maybe move to an Important folder.

The author says to make a `~/.forward` file like this:

```
# Exim filter

save Maildir/.Archive
```

explaining:

> What this does is put all mail that is recieved into the Archive subdirectory (the dots are convention of the version of the Maildir format that Courier-IMAP uses).

If I follow these instructions exactly, then Exim4 creates a `Maildir/.Archive` ***file*** and keeps appending the messages to it. But then `notmuch` doesn't find them.

I thought perhaps the author omitted that I need to use `makemaildir` to create a `Maildir/.Archive` ***directory***. So I tried that, but then Exim4 doesn't store the messages. Instead `var/log/exim4/mainlog` has entries like this:

```
2013-07-07 21:54:42 1Uvwuo-0007CH-5m == /home/i/Maildir/.Archive <i@domain.com> R=userforward T=address_file defer (-4): mailbox /home/i/Maildir/.Archive has too many links (5)
```

Maybe I'm being dense, but I don't understand what "too many links" means in this regard.

I've been going in circles for many hours and seem completely stuck. Maybe learning about Maildir++, Exim, Courier, and notmuch all at once is too much. Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

*p.s. I would have tagged this `notmuch`, too, but I lack rep.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tail `/` is important here. If you want Maildir delivery then you must use:

```
# Exim filter

save Maildir/.Archive/
```

Comment: Using relative path results in "appendfile: file or directory name "..." is not absolute", but using absolute paths works. @dsznajder is there some Exim4 setting that you enabled to allow relative paths?

Comment: If you don't have `/` it treats it as a normal alias hence it's needed, see file `/etc/exim4/conf.d/transport/35_exim4-config_address_directory` comments on Debian split config system.

Comment: @DanielSokolowski - Maybe you need to set `transport_home_directory` in router to "home" of virtual user.

Answer (score 2):

Best guess is that exim is trying to deliver to an mbox (which is a single file), not maildir. If you run `dpkg-reconfigure exim4-config` and run through, do you have it set to use Maildir?

Note that this will also explain why notmuch is confused, as it only deals with Maildir.

Comment: I double-checked and it is set to use Maildir. Also, if I delete the `.forward` file and let mail be delivered "normally", it ends up in `INBOX` and `notmuch` does see it, as well as messages in `Sent` from doing test sends via IMAP from Thunderbird. The problem I'm having is with following the instructions to have new mail delivered to an `Archive` folder, instead.